# NodeJS compression enabled but still poor performance with lighthouse audit for Angular front end

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku

I have an angular front-end being hosted via nodeJS on Heroku. I have done everything I can think of to optimize the page including using compression but when I audit the page, my lighthouse score is between 15- 20 for performance. Specifically the audit recommends to enable text-compression. Which I thought I have done. I have also included an angular service worker. But I am seeing a report to avoid enormous network payloads ~ 3,264 KB.

Below is my server.js file. Is there something wrong with how I have enabled compression? It seems like it doesn't affect my .js files .css files.

I have also included the Angular server module.

How can I improve this score.

Server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var compression = require('compression')
var app = express();

var HTTP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080

//required to compress data sent to client 
app.use(compression())
app.use(express.static("public"));

//minifies css & js files sent to client for optimization
app.get('*.js', function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
    next();
  });
  app.get('*.css', function(req, res, next) {
    req.url = req.url + '.gz';
    res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    next();
  });


// Redirect Users to "index.html" if route not accessed using client side routing
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"));
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
            // request was via https, so do no special handling
            next();
    } else {
            // request was via http, so redirect to https
            //required for optimaztion 
            res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});

app.listen(HTTP_PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("listening on port: " + HTTP_PORT);
})
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered [lazy-loading modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-feature-modules)?

Comment: Do you have a rewrite proxy? If you do, you can try to enable compression at the proxy level

Comment: @Anonta I had tried to set it up initially but had some issues getting the routes to work when hosted on the nodeJS server. I am still new to angular :\

Comment: @David I did not set one up but looking at the heroku docs it seems like it might be enabled automatically. I actually don't know much about that; still new to hosting, Only been doing web dev seriously for like 8 months

I did note though that there was a large third party resource from heroku adding significant time to the performance audit  but i just assumed it was b/c I still have the free tier dyno

Comment: Easy way to check is look at network tab in your browser and check if files are gzipped or not

Comment: yeah I did that some of them say ```content-encoding: gzip``` and others (like the angular bundle files) have  ```X-Content-Encoding-Over-Network: gzip```